# check substring exsit in array Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

i need to check a specific string exist in jquery array . For this i write the following code .But it is not working . Please help .

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var ar = ["color1:white", "color2:black"];

    if ($.inArray("black", ar) > -1) {
        alert("yes");
    } else {
        alert("no");
    }
});
```

.I need to check black color is in the array. Please help.

Comment: what is a `jquery array`?

Comment: sorry , what is the error in my code ? i didn't understand .

Comment: inArray i already used

Comment: You could also check by inclusion and directly with ``.forEach()``

Comment: could you please give example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to use jquery:

```js
var arr = ["color1:white","color2:black"].map(x => x.split(':')[1]);

console.log(arr); 
console.log(arr.indexOf('black') > -1 ? 'yes' : 'no');
```

Comment: array contain many value , not only this two values . for example var ar = ["color1:white", "color2:black",  "color3:red:yes",  "class-test:div:append"];

Comment: @Jafartm Then, trying to use [forEach()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) method. Something like: `arr.forEach(x => console.log(x.indexOf('substring')));`

Answer (score 0):

Please check if you have properly assigned values to an array. Try below code:

```
if ($.inArray("black", ar) !== -1) {
   alert("yes");
}
else {
   alert("no");
}
```

Comment: This isn't how `$.inArray` works at all